# Update page after provisioning modern page

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-pages, provisioning, pnp-provision

I'm using the Pnp framework to provision a modern site with some web parts on it.

After adding Quick Links web part and open the page I see the text "We didn't find anything to show here." in that web part. If I click edit and then save the Quick Links appears.

Any suggestions how to make this work without have to click edit and save?

Comment: did you get the solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

PnPjs offers an option to modify the control proerties on a modern page programmatically:

```
const page = await sp.web.loadClientsidePage("/sites/s01/SitePages/test.aspx");

  const control = page.findControlById('81b84607-7f7a-49d8-b504-957a986d6e07') as ClientsideWebpart;

  let p = control.getProperties();
  control.setProperties(
    {
      //selectedListId: "83c5528a-ea95-46ad-82d0-61004b0cb839",
      ....
    }
  );

  page.save();
```

For more details, please refer to:

- https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/clientside-pages/

BR